# application level service bindings in cloud foundry for a spring boot app

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, pcf

I have a requirement of binding my spring boot app (which is running on PCF) with mysql service instance of a different microservice. I believe  application level service bindings can help me but I get only a spring cloud stream example here https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-admin-cloudfoundry/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/getting-started-service-binding-at-application-level.html

It would be great if  somebody can help me in finding an example of application specifc service binding in pcf for a spring boot app .

Thanks,
Nilanjan

Comment: You can find some information about it here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-admin-cloudfoundry/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/getting-started-service-binding-at-application-level.html

Answer (score 0):

Nilanjan

As pointed out in the document you've provided you should look at this in two parts

1. The PCF service name - the actual name of your service in PCF (e.g., "foo").
2. The name of your application/microservice (*application* is synonymous to *microservice* in this context)

So, if your *microservice* name is "bar" and PCF service name is "foo", then the directive for binding such service to your application would be:

```
dataflow:>stream deploy --name myFlow --properties "deployer.bar.cloudfoundry.services=foo"
```

Hope this helps, but let us know if it is still unclear or you need some more information.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Mine is not a Stream app, its just a spring boot app. Seems like I have to still use cf bind <mySpringBottapp> with the mysql instance I want to bind with . Please let me know if my assumption is correct.